# s-domain to z-domain conversion in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, laplace-transform, z-transform

I want to convert a transfer function from s-domain to z-domain. But, by keeping variable i.e without assigning values to variables.

I tried to do it with s2z command but it demands numeric input, not variable

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to force yourself to ask a question (and a question that is relevant to this electrical engineering site).

Comment: [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/rf/ref/s2z.html) indicates that `s2z` : "*converts the scattering parameters to the impedance parameters.*" which IMO has nothing to do with transfer functions. You are thinking of `c2d` perhaps ?

Comment: @AJN ... YES, I MEANT c2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the method of conversion.

If you select [Bilinear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform) as the method, the conversion can be done by substitution.
The substitution required
([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform#Discrete-time_approximation)) is

$$
s \mapsto \frac{2}{T} \frac{z-1}{z+1}
$$

e.g. If the transfer function is, \$\frac{k}{s+a}\$, it becomes

$$
\frac{k}{
\frac{2}{T} \frac{z-1}{z+1} + a
}
=
\frac{T\ k\ (z+1)}{(2+a\ T)z + (a\ T -2)}
$$

If you are using symbolic computation, and if the transfer function is available as a symbolic expression, then the `subs` function in symbolic tool box of Matlab can be used.

```matlab
% s and z are symbolic variables
% expression_for_tf is a an expression containing (powers) of s
subs(expression_for_tf, s, 2*(z-1)/(T*(z+1)));
```

Note that there are [other methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform#See_also) for converting a continuous time transfer function to discrete time transfer function. Method selection depends on the application. Other methods may not allow for such a conversion by plain substitution.

Comment: thankyou for your time ... but if only s and z are taken as symbolic variables, then it gives the error about other variables that: " this variable is not defined ". Plus, I know the final solution. this command is not even giving a solution near to that one.

Comment: "*this variable is undefined*" is too vague to give any suggestions. **1)** Use the [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/526019/edit) button under the question to add the details about the code and the error into the question. **2)** Add a minimum non-working code example and the detailed error message into the question. **3)** If you know the solution, add that also into the question. More details, the better. **4)** Add the type of transfer function you have and why it needs to be converted. Even if the code works, it may not be the correct method. Please address all 4 points.